# Ef Core filtering included query using uow and repository

Tags: c#, winforms, ef-core-6.0

I started creating a role-based security system in my WinForm application so I began with Form navigation (Permission Navigation) and this is my entity's

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        UsersToRoles = new HashSet<UsersToRole>();
    }
    
    public string Login { get; set; } = null!;
    public string PasswordUser { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? FullName { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<UsersToRole> UsersToRoles { get; set; }
}
    
public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        UsersToRoles = new HashSet<UsersToRole>();
        PermissionNavigations = new HashSet<PermissionNavigation>();
    }
  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
   
    public virtual ICollection<UsersToRole> UsersToRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PermissionNavigation> PermissionNavigations { get; set; }
}
    
public partial class UsersToRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public int IdRole { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Role IdRoleNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual User IdUserNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
}
    
public partial class Navigation
{
    public Navigation()
    {
        PermissionNavigations = new HashSet<PermissionNavigation>();
    }
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Page { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Forms { get; set; } = null!;
   
    public virtual ICollection<PermissionNavigation> PermissionNavigations { get; set; }
}
    
public partial class PermissionNavigation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdRole { get; set; }
    public int IdNavigation { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Navigation IdNavigationNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Role IdRoleNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

This is my geniric GetAllIncluding method

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    try
    {
         IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
         foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> includeProperty in includeProperties)
         {
             query = query.Include<T, object>(includeProperty);
         }
         return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         throw new Exception($"{nameof(GetAllIncluding)} properties could not be included properly: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it in my PermissionNavigationService

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<PermissionNavigationDto?>> 
    GetAllPermissionNavigationDetailsByUserAsync(int idUser)
{
    var permissionNavigation = await unitOfWork.PermissionNavigations.GetAllIncluding(
                        x => x.IdNavigationNavigation,
                        x => x.IdRoleNavigation,
                        x => x.IdRoleNavigation.UsersToRoles.Where(x=>x.IdUser== idUser));
    
    return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PermissionNavigationDto?>>(permissionNavigation);
}
```

I know that this line of code only filtering UsersToRoles entity not PermissionNavigation entity

```cs
x => x.IdRoleNavigation.UsersToRoles.Where(x=>x.IdUser== idUser)
```

**The question is: What can be done to get all Permission Navigation related to specific user**

**Update1**
I am looking for something like this but in ef core

```sql
SELECT PermissionNavigation.[Id]
      ,PermissionNavigation.[IdRole]
      ,Roles.Name
      ,Navigation.Forms
      ,[IdNavigation]
      ,UsersToRoles.IdUser
    FROM [SIM].[dbo].[PermissionNavigation]
    INNER JOIN Roles on Roles.Id=IdRole
    INNER JOIN Navigation on Navigation.id=IdNavigation
    INNER JOIN UsersToRoles on UsersToRoles.IdRole=PermissionNavigation.[IdRole]
    WHERE UsersToRoles.IdUser=@IdUser
```

**Update2**
I appreciate all the help I received.
I decided to go this way:
When the user has successfully logged in, I catch the Id then I make a call to get all roles related to that user after that I make another call to get all permission navigation using role Id that I got earlier.

```
    List<PermissionNavigationDto> navigationDtos = new();
    var userRoles = await userToRoleService.GetUserRolesAsync(LoginUserDetails.Id);          
    foreach (var role in userRoles)
    {
        var navigation = await permissionNavigationService.GetPermissionNavigationByRoleIdAsync(role.IdRole);
        navigationDtos.AddRange(navigation);
    }
```

Comment: Any reason why UsersToRole has an Id? It should be a Table in db, but in EF, it should be just a relation, not an entity. If you remove Id and correct the mappings, then Role will have Users and User will have Roles; 1 less navigation. Same for PermissionNavigation which is unnecessary as an entity.

Comment: It also would be great if you correct the naming and follow the common naming conventions. For example, instead of IdUser, use UserId. It makes the question more readable.

Comment: I have removed the Id column in UsersToRole table and create a composite key(IdUser,IdRole) .    How can I perform CRUD operations if I remove the UsersToRole entity?

Comment: ASP.NET Identity Core: Look at the [models](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src) including `IdentityUserRole` and look at the [EF contexts and stores](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/sr) including UserStore where you can get list of the user roles, add to a role or remove from a role. In this implementation there's UserRole class and table as well.

Comment: ASP.NET Identity: Look at the [EF related implementations](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/tree/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework) including IdentiyUser, IdentityRole and UserStore. In this implementation, there's no `UserRole` class, while there's the table for that.

Comment: I am not arguing about the solution you provided, I am just not at that level yet, as you can tell from my questions, if we can leave the entities as it is and make a solution, I will be very grateful, I am truly sorry about the inconvenience

Comment: No worries, of course it's completely fine if you leave the question as it is. I just shared the links for *future* leaning purpose.

Comment: With such a complex query it's best to handle it where you have access to the context object. Then refer to these doc links (this)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators] and (this)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins].

Comment: I appreciate all the help I received.
I decided to go this way:
When the user has successfully logged in, I catch the Id then I make a call to get all roles related to that user after that I make another call to get all permission navigation using role Id that I got earlier.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0)

```
//The userId concerned
int userId = 1;

//As an example, let's say you have your repository items below
List<User> users = new List<User>();
List<UsersToRole> userToRoles = new List<UsersToRole>();
List<Role> roles = new List<Role>();            

//if you have to retrieve user
User myUser = users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);

//get all roleIds this user (userId = 1) belongs to
List<int> roleIds = userToRoles.Where(x => x.IdUser == userId).Select(us => us.IdRole).ToList();

//get the role objects, then the PermissionNavigations and flatten it out with SelectMany
List<PermissionNavigation> permissionNavigations = roles.Where(us => roleIds.Contains(us.Id)).Select(us => us.PermissionNavigations).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate all the help I received.
I decided to go this way:
When the user has successfully logged in, I catch the Id then I make a call to get all roles related to that user after that I make another call to get all permission navigation using role Id that I got earlier.